# Xamarin.iOS and NuGet: Circular dependency detected

Tags: xamarin.ios, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to install the FirebaseDatabase.net package in my Xamarin.iOS project, but I get the following error message. Any thoughts?

```
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'FirebaseDatabase.net.3.0.2' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Circular dependency detected 'FirebaseDatabase.net 3.0.2 => System.Reactive 3.1.1 => System.Reactive.PlatformServices 4.0.0-preview00001 => System.Reactive 3.1.1'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually managed to install the package by manually installing the `System.Reactive.PlatformServices 4.0.0-preview00001` package first! The circular dependency is thus broken